# AWS EC2 PHP SDK credentials not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, credentials

I am trying to create a way to programatically start/stop my EC2 instances. This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$ec2 = new \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client([
   'credentials' => [
   'key'    => 'KEY_HERE',
   'secret' => 'SECRET_HERE'
],

   'region' => env('AWS_REGION', 'us-west-2'),
   'version' => 'latest',
   'ua_append' => [
       'L5MOD/' . AwsServiceProvider::VERSION,
   ]
 ]);

$result = $ec2->describeInstanceStatus([
   'InstanceIds' => ['i-c21a366e']
]);
?>
```

Of course I am using my actual keys instead of 'KEY_HERE' and 'SECRET_HERE'.

I am getting this error as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to mention that if I use the S3 service, everything works fine. I am having this problem with the EC2 service only.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you know what IAM policy your account has?

Comment: I created an IAM user and assigned the AmazonEC2FullAccess policy to it. Simulating the describeInstanteStatus policy returns this: http://content.screencast.com/users/alexcontes/folders/Jing/media/49686117-82ef-4e5c-8c5b-4869347484b4/00000064.png so it is only a problem in the code, but using the AWS simulator works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what is going on and I was able to fix it.

Looks like AWS is using server clock for authorizing access and I needed to install the ntp service and update it so that the clock is properly synced.

I installed the ntp server by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Then I updated the services with these commands:

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -gq
sudo service ntp start
```

And problem was fixed.